# Plots and widgets not showing on jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

If I run this code on a `jupyter notebook`

```
from bqplot import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1, title='Line Chart')
np.random.seed(0)
n = 200
x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, n)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(n))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The plot display, but if I run the same code on Jupyter lab I get

```
VBox(children=(Figure(axes=[Axis(scale=LinearScale()), Axis(orientation='vertical', scale=LinearScale())], fig…
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First, run this.

```
$ pip install bqplot
$ jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager 
$ jupyter labextension install bqplot
```

## In a Jupyter notebook

```
import bqplot
```

Then restart jupyter lab. You are ready to go!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the why? What is `bqplot`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi just type this in a cell and then run it, it should work!

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: I got the same output. I am having the same issue with ipywidgets